# Trying to eliminate closure error in google map eventListener

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I have a google map with a load of markers on it, each corresponding to a different post in the html. Each marker id is the same as each post id. Inside the map `initialize = function() {...` I have the following code (I'm using gon to pass info from rails to javascript):

```
for (m = 0; m < gon.markers.length; m++) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(gon.markers[m].lat, gon.markers[m].lng),
    icon: image,
    infowindow: gon.markers[m].infowindow,
    id: gon.markers[m].id
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
    var image = $("#map-canvas").data('marker2');
    this.setIcon(image);
    // console.log("marker.id: " + marker.id);
    // console.log("this.id" + this.id);
    $('#' + marker.id).css('background', 'red');
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
    var image = $("#map-canvas").data('marker1');
    this.setIcon(image);
    $('#' + marker.id).css('background', 'white');
  });
  markers[markers.length] = marker;
}
```

Uncommenting the `console.log` lines demonstrates that it is the classic closure problem (marker.id always has the same value no matter which marker is hovered on).

My question is, how do I code it properly so it does as intended? I just can't get the code right now matter what I try. I've tried stuff like this but is just doesn't work:

```
  marker.on('mouseover', noticeHover(marker.id));
  function noticeHover(id) {
    var image = $("#map-canvas").data('marker2');
    this.setIcon(image);
    $('#' + id).css('background', 'gainsboro');
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the entire code that handles the marker-creation into a function and pass the items inside the loop as argument to this function:

```
    for (m = 0; m < gon.markers.length; m++) {
      //anonymous,self-executing function 
      (function(props){
        var goo     = google.maps,
            marker  = new goo.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: new goo.LatLng(props.lat, 
                                                 props.lng),
                        icon: image,
                        infowindow: props.infowindow,
                        id: props.id
                      });
        goo.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
          var image = $("#map-canvas").data('marker2');
          this.setIcon(image);
          $('#' + marker.id).css('background', 'red');
        });

        goo.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
          var image = $("#map-canvas").data('marker1');
          this.setIcon(image);
          $('#' + marker.id).css('background', 'white');
        });
        markers.push(marker);
       }(
          gon.markers[m]//pass current loop-item as argument 
        ));

     }
```